# Is argparse capable of enforcing that a positional argument be required and return a string value?

Tags: python, argparse

```
parser.add_argument('domain_name', metavar='domain name',
                    action='store', nargs=1, help='specify a domain name')
```

See the above line of code. It requires that the positional argument be specified, but it returns a list. To access `domain_name`, I need to access `args.domain_name[0]`. I'd like to access it as `args.domain_name` as it's confusing to see this list that can only ever be one item, and in fact must be one item as it's required.

If I specify `nargs='*'` it's no longer required but is returned as a string.

Comment: Why don't you *not set `nargs`*? [*"Note that `nargs=1` produces a list of one item. This is different from the default, in which the item is produced by itself."*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nargs isn't a required parameter and its removal will return a string and not a list as specified above.